# How to control multiple overlays via checkboxes?

Tags: image, checkbox, overlay

I have a map in a few different layers.

One image is basically just land.  Another image is the borders with everything else transparent.  Another image is colors of individual countries with everything else transparent.

I would like to have 2 check boxes on the page that are basically `Show borders? []` and `Show colors? []`.

I'm really unsure how to make my checkbox do anything other than be checked or not.

Hoping someone can help.